# How can I fill a PHP dropdownbox with all the elements of a (part of) WSDL data?

Tags: select, soapui, currency, demo

When you download SoapUI there is a nice example for a WSDL on currency....

this one: http://www.webservicex.com/currencyconvertor.asmx?WSDL

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
<s:element name="ConversionRate">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FromCurrency" type="tns:Currency"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ToCurrency" type="tns:Currency"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:simpleType name="Currency">
<s:restriction base="s:string">
<s:enumeration value="AFA"/>
<s:enumeration value="ALL"/>
<s:enumeration value="DZD"/>
<s:enumeration value="ARS"/>
<s:enumeration value="AWG"/>
<s:enumeration value="AUD"/>
<s:enumeration value="BSD"/>
<s:enumeration value="BHD"/>
<s:enumeration value="BDT"/>
<s:enumeration value="BBD"/>
<s:enumeration value="BZD"/>
<s:enumeration value="BMD"/>
<s:enumeration value="BTN"/>
```

On my PHP page I'd like to have all the  
in the dropdown box

like so:

```
<select name="eneagram" >
   <option value="USD">USD</option>
   <option value="JPY">JPY</option>
```

What i did manage to do was:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['getdata'])){


//$naam=$_POST['naam'];
//$date=$_POST['date'];
$type=$_POST['type'];
//$core=$_POST['core'];
//$management=$_POST['management'];
//$tools = json_encode($_POST['tools']);
//$tools=$_POST['tools'];
//$analytisch=$_POST['analytisch'];
$eneagram=$_POST['eneagram'];

try{
    $soap_client = new
    //SoapClient("http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL");
    SoapClient("http://www.webservicex.com/currencyconvertor.asmx?WSDL");
   // $vec = array("symbol"=>"DOX");

   $vec = array("FromCurrency"=>"$type", "ToCurrency"=>"$eneagram");
    $quote = $soap_client->ConversionRate($vec);
    echo $quote->ConversionRateResult;
    }
    catch(SoapFault $exception)
    {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }



if(true == false ){
    echo "<label class='err'>All fields are required</label>";
    }

        else{

    }


?>
<script>alert('Calculated the conversion rate!');</script>
<?php }
}
 ?>
```

But now I think I need something of an foreach and then the get from wsdl and then the  select    option   but I don't know exactly how to do it....